# Why won´t build-helper-maven-plugin pass property to javafx-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, javafx, properties, native, build-helper-maven-plugin

I am currently trying to deploy a javafx native bundle. While this basically works fine it won´t deploy to any location given to `<nativeOutputDir>` by a contructed property using build-helper-maven-plugin and its regex-property goal.

Here´s my pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>regex-property</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>regex-property</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                            <name>replaced.deploydir</name>
                            <value>${project.version}</value>
                            <regex>.+SNAPSHOT</regex>
                            <replacement>C:\\\\temp\\\\snapDir</replacement>
                            <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>foo.bar.StartApp</mainClass>
            <nativeOutputDir>${replaced.deployDir}</nativeOutputDir>
            <nativeReleaseVersion>1.1.0</nativeReleaseVersion>
            <updateExistingJar>true</updateExistingJar>
            <additionalAppResources>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</additionalAppResources>
            <appName>InstructionGen</appName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Now when i pass a property just by using mavens property-tag the nativeInstaller will be deployed to the correct location.

While this might be correlated to [question]: ([Maven build-helper-maven-plugin regex unable to use property as dependency.version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483586/maven-build-helper-maven-plugin-regex-unable-to-use-property-as-dependency-versi)).
That question does not support an answer in my opinion.
The phase in which the replacement takes place is "validate", whereas the phase in which the javafx-maven-plugin builds the bundle is "package", so order should be correct.
I used the antrun-plugin for tests to see if the property is created at all, and it is.
Interesting fact: When I add something after `${replaced.deployDir}` in `<nativeOutputDir>` like `<nativeOutputDir>${replaced.deployDir}\\test</nativeOutputDir>` it deploys to `projectname\target\${replaced.deployDir}\test` creating the non-parsed `${replaced.deployDir}` folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that `replaced.deploydir` was the correct path you were expecting? Run `mvn clean validate -X` (in debug mode) to see if the value is correct.

Comment: I kept running using the -e and -X switch for maximum output.
Path seems to be correct. The replacer resolves `${replaced.deployDir}` to `C:\\temp\\snapDir` which is what i would write into nativeOutputDir directly.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it should replace it to `C:\temp\snapDir` instead. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, I´ve tried, didn´t work. Neither did `c:/temp/snapDir`. Interesting fact: When I add something after `${replaced.deployDir}` like `${replaced.deployDir}\\test` it deploys to `projectname\target\${replaced.deployDir}\test` creating the non-parsed `${replaced.deployDir}` folder. So it is definately not being replaced.